# Solve differential equation: $y''-\dfrac{1}{x}y'+\dfrac{\alpha^2}{x^2}y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

The Bessel differential equation can be written like this $$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'+(1-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{x^2})y=0$$ and one of the linearly independent solutions is the bessel function of the first kind, $J_\alpha(x)$.

If we had the equation $$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'+(k^2-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{x^2})y=0$$ on of the independent solutions would be $J_\alpha(kx)$

Plugging $k = 0$ in the last equation would give me almost my differential equation:$$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{x^2}y=0$$ But I am not sure how to handle the changes of sign.

Comment: Your signs are inconsistent in the question and inside the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differential equations of this form are called Euler differential equations, and they can usually be transformed into equations with constant coefficients via exponential substitution (you can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation))

If we use the substitution - $x=e^t\Rightarrow t=log(x)\Rightarrow y'=\frac{1}{x}y_t,y''=-\frac{1}{x^2}y_t+\frac{1}{x^2}y_{tt}$ we get an equation with constant coefficients:

$y_{tt}-2y_t+\alpha^2=0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Nice. Thank you. I don't know how i missed that. @GSofer, how can I solve the equation if instead of $x^2$ I have an $x$?

Comment: I don't think there is a general method for this family of equations. You could maybe suggest a solution in the form of a power series and find a recursion formula for the coefficients (and hopefully identify the power series with a taylor series of a known function).

Answer (score 1):

This differential equation is of the Euler-Cauchy type. Use the ansatz $y = x^r$ to obtain

$$r(r-1)x^{r-2}+rx^{r-2}-\alpha^2x^{r-2}=0$$

If we assume $x\neq 0$ we obtain

$$r(r-1)+r-\alpha^2=0.$$

This equation has two roots $r_{1,2}$ the general solution is given by

$$y = c_1x^{r_1} + c_2x^{r_2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiplying by $$x^2$$
$$x^2y''-xy'+\alpha^2y=0$$ and make the Ansatz:$$y=e^{\lambda x}$$
so you get $$\lambda_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}+1$$
Can you finish?
For your work: the solution is given by $$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{x}^{1+\sqrt {-{\alpha}^{2}+1}}+{\it 
\_C2}\,{x}^{1-\sqrt {-{\alpha}^{2}+1}}
$$

Comment: Are you sure your ansatz is correct? It looks like the standard ansatz for differential equations with constant coefficients?

Comment: This hint gives also WA